# Add content to the editor

Tags: development, javascript, ribbon, rte

I've developed a ribbon button to Sharepoint inside Media tab. This opens a dialog where I list loads of content. On click I'm calling a function to close the dialog and it is supposed to insert some html into the editor.

....

```
options.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback);
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

.... this is the function that I'm returning

```
function CloseCallback(result, target) {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(RTEActions, "sp.ui.rte.js");
}

function RTEActions() {
    RTE.Cursor.update();
    var html = 'testing';
    var rawRange = RTE.Selection.getSelectionRange().$C;
    RTE.DomHelper.pasteHtmlIntoRange(rawRange, html);
}
```

This is throwing an error: rawRange is undefined. Is there a better way to insert content into the editor?

Comment: This question seems to have a solution http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76371/spservices-retrieving-rich-text-values

Comment: it doesn't seem to be the same issue. My intention is to insert text/html where the cursor is. I need to add this just like we can add a table or picture.

Comment: Check out this question and answer, there may be something in there that helps: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34089/sharepoint-rte-how-to-attach-to-mousedown-events-like-bold-italic-does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function RTEActions() {
    RTE.Cursor.update();
    var html = 'testing';
    RTE.Selection.getSelectionRange().pasteHtml(html);
}
```

A word of warning - this only works properly if the cursor is inside the RTE when the function runs - otherwise "testing" is inserted at the top of the page above everything else.

Comment: I'm running the function from the modal dialog that is shown after I click on a Ribbon control. Removing rawRange caused an error:  rawRange.extractContents is not a function. If you click on "Link" button, it popups a window, you type whatever link you need, click OK and it puts the html on the editor. That's actually what I want but can't find a way for this to work

Comment: If you specify a function as the value for "dialogReturnValueCallback" then it runs in the context of the main page, NOT the dialog...

Comment: the it should work right? Because I want to paste the content on the main page...the dialog it's just to return that content. And "dialogReturnValueCallback" is specified as a function, that's where I'm running RETActions()

Comment: Just to clarify, i didn't just remove the the third line of function RTEActions, I removed lines 3 and 4 and replaced them with a different line. Also, my code is tested and works on my page.

Comment: That's it! It was my fault! You code works perfectly and it's just what I needed. Sorry about that confusion and thank you :)

Comment: Great! Glad to help.

Comment: Hi @Chloraphil  i tried the above code in a script editor webpart and and the corresponding button on content editor web part. On page edit mode, i have placed cursor inside the CEWP, but on click on the button, the page refreshes and nothing happens. please help.